# If i have multiple systems in an organization with different DB. Is Neo4J support all of them to put together

Tags: neo4j

Let's take it like an organization having multiple divisions maintained in multiple database systems. If I want to create a neo4j Knowledge graph for all the DB's using neo4j how can we do that? which shouldn't affect the current scenario and the knowledge graph should be up and running?

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j Enterprise Edition 4.0 introduced support for [Fabric](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/fabric/introduction/), which is:

> a way to store and retrieve data in multiple databases, whether they
> are on the same Neo4j DBMS or in multiple DBMSs, using a single Cypher query.